# Host (Win10) disk-size reported wrong after docker builds in VirtualBox on guest (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, docker

My issue is reproducible in a rather specific setup, so let's first give some context:

```
Host OS: Windows 10
Virtual Box 6.0.14 (latest)
Guest OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 (kernel: 5.3.0-24-generic)
Gitlab-runner: 12.5.0
Docker: 19.03.2 (latest)
CMake: 3.16 (latest)
ninja-build: latest
Dynamic VDI: 150Gig (max-use is ~ 70 Gig)
```

A gitlab-runner is executing shell commands inside a Linux guest OS in a Virtual Box on top of the host OS (Windows 10). The host disk is 250Gig in total, while the dynamic linux partition is set tot 150 Gig max, leaving about 60 Gig free Gitlab-runner syncs the project source from an external submodule git, builds a docker (based on top of gcc:8 and dependencies) and pushes it to a repository. It then builds a second docker that executes a number of CMake/ninja install build runs on top of the source. If too many commands are within that docker (like, more than 10 RUN layers) the host OS suddenly drops from 60 GB of free space to mere kilobytes, prompting the host OS (Windows 10) to display a blue warning box that disk-space is critically low. Virtual Box will then suspend the guest OS (Ubuntu), and everything halts.

If I keep an eye on the disk space in the Host OS during this process, the free space stays the same until it starts to disappear. After that, Windows Explorer and the Disk Management tool report that the drive is almost full (Kb's), while WinDirStat can't find the missing gigabytes.

Strangely enough, I can recover from this by rebooting the host OS (the entire PC), after which the free size is reported correctly again, and I can restart the VM and restart the build.

```
Q1: What is causing this sudden disappearing of free disk space?
Q2: Is there a way to fix it without having to reboot (and exit the VM)?
Q3: Has anyone else experienced similar strangeness regarding the disk free size being misreported in certain cases?
```

**Note**

This question was asked first (and closed bc off-topic) on SO, but might be more relevant on this forum.

I also tried TreeSize Free instead of WinDirStat, but it too was unable to point to the files taking up the 'lost' space. Whenever I launch a docker process inside the VM, the issue starts re-occuring again.

Comment: I have no idea what could be the issue, but the last sentence sounds a lot like Windows marking an arbitrary portion of the partition as "reserved", which will never show in the filesystem as there's no file actually consuming that space, but I don't have the knowledge required to elaborate or investigate your issue.

Comment: hmm, so it may be related to how ntfs works. good point, thanks

Comment: I'm trying to recall what I was executing when I ran into what I described above, but it was a couple of years ago... if this is indeed what's going on, there should be a setting that can be enabled/disabled to prevent this, but someone more experienced than I will need to chime in.

Comment: For future reference, I also tried this on a SSD disk, and even when on a native linux host running the virtual box with linux guest and docker, this same issue re-occurs. I am now running the docker job in the host, without virtual box, and so far it seems to do fine.